# How to get latitude and longitude from an address scraping google maps?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the latitude and longitude of an address using a get request, but I'm having a hard time with this.

The address is formed by the street name, a number and a sector of the city. In this case, the street name is `Hernando de Magallanes`, the number is `958` and the sector is `Las Condes`.

My code looks as follows:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

url = "https://www.google.cl/maps/place/Hernando+de+Magallanes+958,+Las+Condes"
resp=requests.request(method="GET",url=url)

soup_parser = soup(resp.text, "html.parser")
```

The part I'm looking for is under script, which is under hmtl tag.

```
html_content = soup_parser.html.contents[1]

_script = html_content.find_all("script")[7]
```

Looking into `_script`, there is a huge load of text, but the part that I'm looking for is the `https` url that is here:

`.... uPfjZVD6AEAACAAAAADAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\",null,null,[[[1,0]\n]\n,1,null,0,0]\n]\n,null,\"Hernando de Magallanes 958, Las Condes, Región Metropolitana\",null,null,\"https://www.google.cl/maps/preview/place/Hernando+de+Magallanes+958,+Las+Condes,+Regi%C3%B3n+Metropolitana/@-33.4164174,-70.5598746,3330a,13.1y/data\\u003d!4m2!3m1!1s0x9662ceef18131219:0x3bab969f4e95bd4e\",1,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,1,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,0,[[[\"W2vSX-_FKMv39QOpipUw\",\"0ahUKEwiv3531h8TtAhXLe30KHSlFBQYQwlUIGCgAMAA\",[\"Hernando d ....`

In particular, I'm looking for the two numbers that are next to the `@` -> `-33.4164174,-70.5598746`.

How can I get this coordinates? Also, I'm thinking to do this for a bunch of other addresses. Is there any daily quota for this requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regular expression regex `re`. and use the pattern.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import re

url = "https://www.google.cl/maps/place/Hernando+de+Magallanes+958,+Las+Condes"
resp=requests.request(method="GET",url=url)

soup_parser = soup(resp.text, "html.parser")

html_content = soup_parser.html.contents[1]

_script = html_content.find_all("script")[7]

matches=re.findall("(-\d+\.\d{7})",_script.text)
print(matches[0],matches[1])
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to view the source code of the page and parse `window.APP_INITIALIZATION_STATE` variable block using a regular expression, there you'll find all needed data. Or you can use browser automation such as [`playwright`](https://playwright.dev/python/) or [`selenium`](https://www.selenium.dev/) instead, but it will be slower.

---

You can also use [Google Maps API](https://serpapi.com/google-maps-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan to test out.

Code to integrate:

```
import os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
    "engine": "google_maps",
    "type": "search",
    "q": "Hernando de Magallanes 958 Las Condes",
    "ll": "@40.7455096,-74.0083012,14z",
    "google_domain": "google.com",
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY") # https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getenv
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

coordinates = results["place_results"]["gps_coordinates"]
latitude = coordinates['latitude']
longitude = coordinates['longitude']

print(f"Latitude: {latitude}\nLongitude: {longitude}")
```

Output:

```
Latitude: -33.4164174
Longitude: -70.5598746
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code snippet and modify it accordingly? (Not knowing exactly what's your search criteria and code sample, just take this as sample).

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36',}
response = get("https://www.google.com/search?q=latitude+longitude+of+75270+postal+code+paris+france",headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
a = soup.find("div", class_= "Z0LcW").text
print(a)
```

Output:

```
48.8573° N, 2.3370° E
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! I added some details of the address and street names. Also, added the url I'm using (I forgot to add that when writing the question). Regarding the code sample, what I've posted is pretty much what I have for now. I'm trying to figure it out how to get the latitude and longitude of the mentioned address and then I would like to replicate the same for other addresses.